# non-commutative generators when using Sympy

Tags: python, scipy, sympy

```
%reset -f
from sympy import *
import sympy as sym
from sympy.solvers import solve
b1=sym.Array([[Rational(-1/2),sqrt(3)/2,0],[-sqrt(3)/2,Rational(-1/2),0],[0,0,1]])
Sigma=[]
List=[]
x, y, z = symbols('\sigma_{11} \sigma_{12} \sigma_{13}',commutative=False)
k, m, n = symbols('\sigma_{21} \sigma_{22} \sigma_{23}',commutative=False)
f, g, h = symbols('\sigma_{31} \sigma_{32} \sigma_{33}',commutative=False)
a1 = sym.Matrix([[x, y, z], [k,m,n], [f, g,h]])
for i in range(0,3):
     for j in range(0,3):
        args = []
        lists=[]
        for k in range(0,3):
            for l in range(0,3):
                x= symbols(('\sigma_{%d%d}')%(k+1,l+1),commutative=False)
                M=sym.Array([x])
                Sigmatotal_tmp=tensorproduct(b1[i][k],b1[j][l],M)
                args.append(Sigmatotal_tmp[0])
    Sigma.append(Add(*args))
```

When trying to execute `solve(Sigma)` I get the error

```
non-commutative generators: (\sigma_{11}, \sigma_{12}, 
\sigma_{13}, \sigma_{21}, \sigma_{22}, \sigma_{23}, \sigma_{31}, 
\sigma_{32}, \sigma_{33})
```

I tried several ways, they all give either error or wrong answer. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

In your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61951623/solving-system-of-linear-equation-with-sympy) you say that you don't want `x + y = y + x`. This is not what SymPy means when it says something is commutative or not. If `x` and `y` are not commutative then `x*y != y*x`. I am not aware of anything in SymPy that will deal with the property that you are dealing with.

The solution to your equations (consistent with your hand solution indicated in comments) is the answer obtained in the original question.

Comment: So, I can only deal with symmetrical operation where the order does'nt matter ? Than, if I want to find the solutions of my 9 equation when sigma_{ij} =0 and I want to look at the dependency between the Sigma's, is this possible?![Equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeIgw.png).

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `sigma_{ij}=0`? Do you mean only `sigma_{ii}` is potentially non-zero?

Comment: The set of the 9 equation's have 9 variables, Sigma_{11},Sigma{12}.....Sigma_{33}. I would like to find the dependence between these variables. The results by hand gives that Sigma_{11]=Sigma{22} and that Sigma_{12}=-Sigma_{21} and finally Sigma_{33} is independent, the other Sigma_{ij} =0.  See the link ![Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61951623/solving-system-of-linear-equation-with-sympy). Maybe I should Write Capital Sigma on the left of the equations

Comment: That is the solution that you get if you use the code given (now modified) in the original question....with commutative symbols.

Comment: Thanks again. For the other case which implies x*y !=y*x I will try to look somewhere else. Thanks for your effort